# Can you get a list of connected devices in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, usb

Im new to java and am just wondering if you can receive a list of connected USB devices, for example:

If i created a java program to modify devices, i want the JFrame to display a list of devices for the user to select one... (That's not my idea, or my intention but that is the best example i can think of, sorry.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `javax.usb` library, we can get information about the `UsbHostManager`.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.usb.*;

public class USBLister {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UsbException {
    //Get UsbHub
    UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
    UsbHub root = services.getRootUsbHub();

    listPeripherique(root);
  }

 public static void listPeripherique(UsbHub hub) {
    //List all the USBs attached
    List perepheriques = hub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
    Iterator iterator = perepheriques.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

      UsbDevice perepherique = (UsbDevice) iterator.next();
      System.out.println(perepherique);

      if (perepherique.isUsbHub())
        listPeripherique((UsbHub) perepherique);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add download link to javax?

Comment: @BenLockyear http://sourceforge.net/projects/javax-usb/ Google is always a great resource. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for Storage Media :-)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class FileStoreMountPoint {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            for( var fileStore : FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores() ) {

                var str = fileStore.toString();
                
                var rootPath = Paths.get( str.substring( 0, str.indexOf("(") ).trim() );
                
                try { 
                    Files.newDirectoryStream( rootPath ).forEach( path -> {
                        System.out.println( path );
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         
     }

}
```